# My EJS's codes is in a string and I can't add array index. How can I add an index number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string, ejs

First and second code don't run. But, when I write a number, third code runs. I write a value for 'number', For example like this, var number = 1;.

I have tried this code,

```
alert("<%- graphic[0].graphics_objects[' + number + ']._id -%>");
```

but it didn't.. How can I write a index number in it?

First code:

```
alert("<%- graphic[0].graphics_objects[number]._id -%>");
```

Second code:

```
alert("<%- graphic[0].graphics_objects[<%=number%>]._id -%>");
```

Third code:

```
alert("<%- graphic[0].graphics_objects[1]._id -%>");
```

Comment: `alert("<%= graphic[0].graphics_objects[0]._id %>");` When I write this code with '<=', and it still doesn't work..

Comment: We have no idea what your `graphic` object/array looks like or where `number` comes from. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is my Graphic model,

```
var graphicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    project_id: {
        type: String,
        ref: 'Project',
        required: true
    },
    title: {
        type: String
    }
    graphics_objects: [{
        point_pool_id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Point_pool'
            //required: true
        }
        value: {
            type: String
        }
    }]
});

module.exports = restful.model('Graphic', graphicSchema);
```

This is project.ejs

```
    for (var number= 0; number< '<%-graphic[0].graphics_objects.length-%>'; number++) {
        go_id = '<%- graphic[0].graphics_objects[number]._id -%>';

    }
```

Comment: This for loop is in script tag